# Face Detection Using Core Image iOs

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-image

I'm trying to make an app using Core Image which detects human faces and extracts their eyes. The problem is it detects animal faces as well. Can anyone please tell me if there is a way to avoid animal face detection from that using Core Image itself, or is there any condition to do so?

Comment: you can write you own algorithm for face detection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CIFaceFeature class can give you the positions of eyes, mouth, isSmiling, etc. Hypothetically, you could manually check for "out of bounds" type features, which may imply an animal, a drawing, and not a human.